# Drupal Cache_clear_all error

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have an error when I or Drupal run Cache_clear_all().
I had this error on a Wamp server, and also an AquiaDesktop server (after 1 day of work. It worked well during 1 day on AquiaServer. It depends perhaps on my development but there is the problem on my local Wamp for a long time).
I have import new databases of my project (from production) and the problem occures again.

The problem does not occur on other machins and servers (development, test, production servers).

On a new database (import from production),
the error when I run drush cc all is :

```
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib>drush cc all
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or    [error]
view not found: 1146 Table
'cnsa_siteweb_test_contrib.cache_views_data' doesn't exist' in
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\database\database.inc:2171
Stack trace:
#0
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\database\database.inc(2171):
PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\database\database.inc(683):
DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)
#2
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\database\query.inc(933):
DatabaseConnection->query('TRUNCATE {cache...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\cache.inc(513):
TruncateQuery->execute()
#4 C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\cache.inc(165):
DrupalDatabaseCache->clear('*', true)
#5
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\sites\all\modules\contrib\views\views.module(
906):
cache_clear_all('*', 'cache_views_dat...', true)
#6 [internal function]: views_field_update_instance(Array, Array)
#7 C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\module.inc(895):
call_user_func_array('views_field_upd...', Array)
#8
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\modules\field\field.crud.inc(575):
module_invoke_all('field_update_in...', Array, Array)
#9
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\sites\all\modules\contrib\features\includes\f
eatures.field.inc(299):
field_update_instance(Array)
#10 [internal function]:
field_instance_features_rebuild('iteration51', 'field_instance')
#11
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\sites\all\modules\contrib\features\features.m
odule(582):
call_user_func_array('field_instance_...', Array)
#12
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\sites\all\modules\contrib\features\features.m
odule(984):
features_invoke('field_instance', 'features_rebuil...',
'iteration51')
#13
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\sites\all\modules\contrib\features\features.m
odule(1012):
_features_restore('rebuild', Array)
#14
C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\sites\all\modules\contrib\features\features.m
odule(272):
features_rebuild()
#15 [internal function]: features_flush_caches()
#16 C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\module.inc(895):
call_user_func_array('features_flush_...', Array)
#17 C:\Aquia\cnsa-siteweb-test-contrib\includes\common.inc(7487):
module_invoke_all('flush_caches')
#18 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\commands\core\drupal\cache.inc(90):
drupal_flush_all_caches()
#19 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes\drush.inc(694):
drush_cache_clear_both()
#20 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes\drush.inc(686):
drush_call_user_func_array('drush_cache_cle...', Array)
#21 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\commands\core\cache.drush.inc(143):
drush_op('drush_cache_cle...')
#22 [internal function]: drush_cache_command_clear('all')
#23 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(359):
call_user_func_array('drush_cache_com...', Array)
#24 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(210):
_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#25 [internal function]: drush_command('all')
#26 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(178):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#27 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot.php(46):
drush_dispatch(Array)
#28 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(76):
Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#29 C:\Program Files
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(16): drush_main()
#30 {main}
```

The error in mysql.err is :

```
InnoDB: File name .\cnsa_siteweb_test_contrib\cache_views_data.ibd
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
150225 16:47:27  InnoDB: Error creating file '.\cnsa_siteweb_test_contrib\cache_views_data.ibd'.
150225 16:47:27  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
150225 16:47:27  InnoDB: TRUNCATE TABLE cnsa_siteweb_test_contrib/cache_views_data failed to create a new tablespace
150225 17:15:41  InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table cnsa_siteweb_test_contrib/cache_views_data
InnoDB: because the .ibd file is missing.  For help, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
150225 17:15:41 [ERROR] MySQL is trying to open a table handle but the .ibd file for
table cnsa_siteweb_test_contrib/cache_views_data does not exist.
Have you deleted the .ibd file from the database directory under
the MySQL datadir, or have you used DISCARD TABLESPACE?
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
how you can resolve the problem.

The Mysqld server is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\mysql\bin
and the data for the database in C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\mysql\data
```

Any advices ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
>
> InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
>
> InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.

Permissions problem.  For whatever reason, the installation of MySQL did not work right.